# Can't I change the pointer to another one when I use new operator in C++?

Tags: c++, new-operator

I ask you questions because there is something I don't understand while studying dynamic allocation in C++.

Can I delete "St" and use "ptr" instead if I move the address stored in St to another pointer "ptr" when the dynamically allocated memory is pointed by the St pointer?

If I delete the "St" dynamic allocation, can I move the address to another pointer and delete the "St" immediately because the allocated space does not disappear but disconnects the pointer "St" from the space?

Below is the code I was writing.
Student is a structure.

```
 int main()
    {   
       case 1:
        {
            Student* ptr = NULL;
            Student* St = new Student[10];
            ptr = St;
            delete[] St;
            St = NULL;
        break;
       }

      case 2:`enter code here`
      {
        printdata(ptr);break;
      }
    }
```

Comment: You don't delete "a pointer". You delete the memory it's poinitng to. If you have two pointers pointing to the same memory, both are invalidated.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I imagine you know this but you can delete a pointer if it has dynamic storage duration, e.g. a pointer member of a node in a linked list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've called `delete[]` on the pointer you get back from `new Student[10]`, the value of that pointer is *indeterminate*. Both `St` and `ptr` are exactly that, but you reassign `St`. (Since C++11, use `nullptr` rather than `NULL`.)

The behaviour of dereferencing the pointer you get back from `new Student[10]` following the `delete[]` is *undefined*.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use memory you just freed. Memory at that address might still be usable (event till program closes), but there is no guarantee and program might use it for something else.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I delete "St" and use "ptr" instead if I move the address stored
> in St to another pointer "ptr" when the dynamically allocated memory
> is pointed by the St pointer?

If St points toward your array, you can make ptr point toward it as well, but it is not a transfer. What you actually transfer is the adress of the object you are pointing to. The 2 pointers will point toward the same object.

If you delete the object with delete[] (you delete the object, not the pointer), then the 2 pointers will point toward nothing. So what you actually want to do here is make ptr point toward the same object, and then make St point toward null.

```
Student* ptr = NULL;
Student* St = new Student[10];
ptr = St;
St = NULL;
```

**Edit :** If it may help you understand, here is what you can display ...

```
int x = 4;
int* p = &x;
cout << "x = " << x << " value of x." << endl;
cout << "&x = " << &x << " adress of x." << endl;
cout << "*p = " << *p << " the value of what p points to." << endl;
cout << "p = " << p << " the actual value of p which is the adress of x." << endl;
```